# How to copy files and retain the structure in gnu makefiles?

Tags: makefile

For example, given a list of files in current directory, how to copy the files into another directory.

```
dest_dir := /usr/bin/test

.PHONY: install
install: $(dest_dir)

#there files are in current directory
xpi_built := install.rdf \
             chrome.manifest \
             $(wildcard content/*.js) \
             $(wildcard content/*.xul) \
             $(wildcard content/*.xml) \
             $(wildcard content/*.css) \
             $(wildcard skin/*.css) \
             $(wildcard skin/*.png) \
             $(wildcard locale/*/*.dtd) \
             $(wildcard locale/*/*.properties)

#how to copy there files to another directory
$(dest_dir)/% : $(xpi_built)
    @mkdir -p $(dest_dir)
    @cp $< $@
```

How could I copy the list of files into the destination directory?

Answer (score 0):

```
.PHONY: copy_files

copy_files: $(xpi_built)
    @mkdir -p $(dest_dir)
    @cp $^ $(dest_dir)
```

Comment: cp -R cannot preserve the directory structure.

Comment: @Jichao: You're right, my mistake, I'll edit. I'm also working on a variant to copy files only if they actually need to be copied (that is if they haven't already been copied, or are out of date) but that's hard to make simple.

Comment: You could add a dummy target/file to keep track of that.  That is, use `$(dest_dir)/.copyfiles: $(xpi_built)`, where the last rule is `touch $@`.   The `$(dest_dir)/.copyfiles` file will have a date on it, so it will only be updated if one of the built files is newer.  Also, if you nuke $(dest_dir), it will rerun.